# Typescript declaration for global function

Tags: javascript, typescript, definitelytyped

I am trying to use image loading third party plugin [blueimp](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image). That plugin has global function

```
loadImage(
    e.target.files[0],
    function (img) {
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    },
    { maxWidth: 600 }
);
```

How can I call this function using typescript?

Comment: Here is a quick migration guide : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript: What to do if a typings (or tsd) is not available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834121/typescript-what-to-do-if-a-typings-or-tsd-is-not-available)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put the following line before the function call:

```
declare var loadImage;
```

[[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=declare%20var%20loadImage%3B%0A%0AloadImage(%0A%20%20%20%20e.target.files%5B0%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20function%20(img)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20document.body.appendChild(img)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20maxWidth%3A%20600%20%7D%0A)%3B)]