# Can you teach VSC linter your own syntax?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, global-variables, linter, global-functions

So I'm out here writing code and I was wondering whether you can teach the VSC linter some syntax errors it catches.

I say this because I installed a JS file globally in my angular app. I have a function called log() that logs to the console without having to write that whole `console.log(* * *)` bs.

The function works perfectly globally since I put the stated the file in the scripts array in angular.json. However, the problem is that since the function isn't visually available in each and every one of my component's ts files, the linter marks it as an error...

Is there a fix to this other than completely disabling the linter?

Comment: If you’re using TypeScript, you just need a definition file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript declaration for global function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395615/typescript-declaration-for-global-function)